# Octopus out of water

Tags: marine-biology

I was watching a YouTube video where a guy saw an octopus out of water. It was far from a puddle, and looked like it was struggling. He decided to help it get to the next puddle, so he picked it up and said he hoped it did not bite him or ink.

It got me to wonder, what happens when an octopus produces ink out of the water? I tried looking up a video or a Wikipedia entry about it, and did not find anything. Does the ink squirt out in a jet? Does it dribble out into a puddle? Looking it up, I know the ink is expelled from their siphons, but I have not found anything about octopuses expelling ink when out of water.

Comment: Does this help <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_ink>?

Comment: It is definitely interesting information, but it does not address what happens when (or if) an octopus tries expelling ink when out of water.